# Error: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently using Android Studios. I am having trouble compiling my file. I keep getting that error. I searched similar questions but it hasn't helped me.

private void queryBooks(String searchString) {

```
    // Prepare your search string to be put in a URL
    // It might have reserved characters or something
    String urlString = "";
    try {
        urlString = URLEncoder.encode(searchString, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        // if this fails for some reason, let the user know why
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Create a client to perform networking
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    // Have the client get a JSONArray of data
    // and define how to respond
    client.get(QUERY_URL + urlString,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    // Display a "Toast" message
                    // to announce your success
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // 8. For now, just log results
                    Log.d("omg android", jsonObject.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                    // Display a "Toast" message
                    // to announce the failure
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Log error message
                    // to help solve any problems
                    Log.e("omg android", statusCode + " " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error stack?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing }

Comment: please post your error log.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging my program. I found my answer. I was missing }); before closing my program. Thank you everyone for helping me.